# timestamp and scheduled post irregularities

Tags: date-time, server, scheduled-posts, timezones, timestamp

Update: I've confirmed the problem (that scheduled posts are based on UTC time), now just need advice and background to determine best solution. Questions:
**1)** how WP determines UTC time before calculating local timezone offset  (i.e. does it use server OS time or some other source--can't find in codex/googling)
..which would help me answer..

**2)** is changing server time from UTC to local PST the only/best way to make scheduled posts use the same timezone as WP-time? and
**2a)** are there any potential negative implications to changing server time from UTC to local?
**3)** what's the best way to change server time in an accurate way--when I set a clock, it doesn't have to be exactly right, but I'd be concerned about manually setting the time on a server.

Hi all-

Problem: First, WP started missing publication of scheduled posts. This seems to be a widely-experienced issue, and I fixed it by using the "missed schedule" plugin. This is probably, but not necessarily, irrelevant background.

Soon after a move to a new server, WP started publishing scheduled posts early, which to me, can only point to misconfigured time/date settings somewhere in our stack.

Stack: LNMP, one nginx box, one db/memcache/php box (though I didn't, and couldn't, build it)

As far as I know, there are 4 places in our stack where time is set/relied upon: in WordPress General Settings (set to PST, but also correctly displays UTC server time), for PHP5 in php.ini (was set to central time where the new server is, but I updated to PST and restarted php-fpm once I realized PHP5 has a timezone setting, decreasing the discrepancy by 2 hours), and each box's OS (both are set to UTC time, which I have been assuming is ok because WP recognizes it as such as can still set its 'own' time).

Yet, I'm currently watching something occur that shouldn't be possible. A post was set to publish at 9:30am pst, but published at 1:30am pst instead (9:30am utc). This caused the "published X ago" relative timestamp on the post to count backwards from 8 hours, and then start counting up again at 9:30am pst. To me, this means that while the post scheduler (seemingly) should be looking to the (correctly configured) local WP time (as the frontend is), it's instead using UTC (server) time.

Solution options:
A. re-set both boxes' OS, plus PHP, plus all WP blogs to only use utc time, and instruct all editorial to live in UTC.
B. re-set both boxes' OS to PST to match PHP and WP. **It seems like this is probably the solution (since the post published on server/UTC time)**, but I'm a *nix n00b and just want to make sure that I should use 'date -s' and just try to be as accurate as possible, **or if it would be smarter just to leave a host support ticket asking them to sync both servers' times to PST?** (or if there's a better way to be precise about it)

What I don't get:
A. Why does the post scheduler disregards "WP time" to make its calculation of when to publish?
(update: I think the answer is here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event - it parses time via unix timestamp directly, rather than through wp?)
B. Why even have WP settings separating UTC time from local time, if all functions don't calculate time from the same source?

Why this is an issue:
We have 15 sites, with primary site users in different timezones. Ideally, they could set WP "local time" per blog, and have all post scheduling and functions rely on that specified time. If scheduling is based on server time, this seems impossible.

Comment: Not sure if that is the cause but The action will trigger when someone visits your WordPress site, if the scheduled time has passed.

Comment: Yeah, I see that. These are relatively high-traffic sites, so they have at least 1 visitor/sec all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters try [Core Control](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/core-control/) plugin to see if scheduled tasks are accurately assigned. Scheduled posts will show up as `publish_future_post` > `check_and_publish_future_post()` with post's ID as argument.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on that plugin. Installed, created test post to publish "tomorrow" and it does show publish_future_post w/ post id as arg, but I don't see check_and_publish_future_post() after **Hooked functions:** -- it's just blank. All other crons do have a corresponding hooked function.  
Any insight on what this missing function means? Thanks!

Comment: @David Anderson not sure, never looked that deep into it - just checked and described how scheduled post comes up on my local test stack

Comment: Okay, thanks. Scheduled posts do publish, so I'm not as concerned about the function, just the timing & trigger. Hence the bold questions about the best ways to ensure timezone settings are consistent in whatever form the scheduling function needs in order to understand correct posting timing..

Comment: @David Anderson does time that Core Control shows for scheduled task make sense? Is it in line with WP time?

Comment: That was the first thing I checked on my test post. The "Due Time" looks to be working properly, and updates when I updated the scheduled time to publish.

Comment: Update: the "Due Time" looks to be reporting "properly" (i.e. scheduled for tomorrow at 11:30am == "2011-01-30 11:30:00 --800"), but I think is also getting to the heart of the problem:

When a user schedules a post, they expect that time to be based on the blog's time, not UTC time. and it looks like the cron scheduler is saying "publish at whatever time it is pacific time when it's 11:30 UTC" -- causing a post to publish 8 hours early in this case.

I guess I could solve it by telling users "to schedule a post, translate your local time to UTC and use that"?

Comment: @David Anderson scheduled time should be adjusted so post is published when it is scheduled to in post edit screen. Comments are not too suited for this, please add new information to origial question. Maybe you could put together example set - what post edit screen shows, what core control shows and when post is really published? It is hard for me to interpret your timezones.

Comment: Update 2: I tested my hypothesis by setting the test post to post a few minutes in the future UTC time (i.e. 20:18, or 12:18 PST), and it DID post. Yay. Now, when I look at the test post on the frontend, it says "posted 8 hours ago" -- because that calculation works off of WP time. Why doesn't scheduling as well!?

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! Now that I have a working workaround, the primary task for me is to figure out the best way to close the time gap, either by updating the OS timezone on our servers (which I fear may create other problems) or by asking our host to do it--and I think all of that info is in the original question, bolded. the information that would help me is: [placed as update to original question]